# Counting occurence between two columns

Tags: python, pandas

Data-

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'city':['abc','abc','abc','ced','def','def'],'zone':['AA','BB','CC','DD','EE','FF'],'D':[22,22,32,76,9,66]})
```

I want to create a new dataframe which has all the zones which have count less than 40 with the city name. I attempted to write the code but I was wondering if there is a more pandas solution for it.

Output-

```
city zone
abc  AA
abc  BB
abc  CC
def  EE
```

My attempt-

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
for zone in new_df['OPS_ZONE']:

    if new_df['OPS_ZONE']==zone & new_df['count'] <40:

        df.append(new_df['OPS_ZONE']==zone)
```

Comment: `df.loc[df.D.lt(40),:'zone']`?

Comment: or  , `df[df['D'].lt(40)].drop('D',1)` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
df[df['D']<40].loc[:,['city','zone']]
```

Explanation: df[df['D']<40] helps us to get all the rows with 'D'<40. Now using loc[] helps us to get specific rows & columns. the first value of loc[,] is ':' representing all rows (that have passed the previous criteria) & ['city','zone'] represent the column to print

Comment: Chaining indexing operations here doesn't make sense. Why not index with `df['D']<40` along the first axis? Why take a full slice?

Answer (score 0):

**Method-1:**
You can use numpy.where() as follows in conjunction with pandas DataFrame:

```
df.loc[list(np.where(df['D'] < 40)[0]), ['city', 'zone']]
```

Here `np.where(df['D'] < 40)` returns a tuple and `np.where(df['D'] < 40)[0]` selects the first element of the tuple which is the array containing indices of the rows having D < 40. Finally, list() converts it from array to list.
Finally, you use .loc() to get the desired columns from 'df'.

**Method-2:**

```
# condition for filtering-
search_cond = df['D'] < 40

# return a slice of Pandas DataFrame satisfying the condition-
df.loc[search_cond, ['city', 'zone']]
```